# Parse error in Artisan when running "laravel new appName"

Tags: php, laravel

I recently decided to use Laravel and tried to create a test application to see how it works. I ran

```
laravel new appName
```

and got this error:

```
Parse error: parse error, expecting "identifier (T_STRING)"' or `"variable
(T_VARIABLE)"' or `'{'' or `'$'' in /Users/ramibazzi/testApp/artisan on line 31

Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned
with an error

  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output:

run-script [--dev] [--no-dev] [-l|--list] [script] [args1] ... [argsN]
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image: compiler screenshot]

What is this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running a version of PHP below 5.5. The [line the parse error is occurring on](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/16e37cb3704d1dc0bb7a55ef1747eb3c742f439f/artisan#L31) reads:

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class);
```

This is illegal in PHP 5.4. The feature being used here, [classname resolution via `::class`](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.class-name), was added in PHP 5.5; prior to that, trying to use `class` as a static property was a syntax error.

At the time of writing, the Laravel [installation docs](http://laravel.com/docs/installation) list the minimum version of PHP required to run Laravel as 5.5.9. Upgrade PHP to version 5.5.9 or later, and try again.

Comment: Yup it was the PHP version. I updated it and now it works perfectly. Thank you @mark

Comment: I figured this out too. But is there a way around this? I mean, i wanna use this version of laravel but i'm stuck at PHP 5.4 because i don't know what other systems i might break in the server.

Comment: @jagc I doubt there's any easy way to make Laravel work on an unsupported version of PHP; you'd have to go through the entire codebase replacing modern PHP functions and constructs with ones supported by the version you want to use. I've never attempted such a thing and don't plan to.